# Finding possible interval for correlation coefficient under a certain correlation structure

Tags: correlation, matrix, eigenvalues

I want to determine the interval for possible values of the correlation coefficient under certain correlation structures (eg. Compound Symmetry, Autoregressive and Banded Toeplitz).

I can do it by checking the sign of its eigenvalue for a given matrix size.

Is it possible to find it analytically?